# capture `pwd` from unix background process at runtime

Tags: shell, unix, pwd

I have one shell script running in background at my terminal:-

```
#!/bin/bash
while true ;
do
var=`pwd`
echo $var
sleep 3;
done
```

current working directory is

```
/home/mydir/
```

tried invoking script via

```
./test.sh &
/home/mydir/test.sh &
bash /home/mydir/test.sh &
```

output on console is

```
/home/mydir/
```

On same terminal session if I do `cd /home/mydir/myinnerdir` . then output should be `/home/mydir/myinnerdir` . But it is **/home/mydir/**

Goal to achieve:-
If I change my `pwd` to another directory, background process should capture this changed directory. From above shell it is not able to. How to do it? Thanks

Comment: Check if you any alias with `myinnerdir` in your home dir using below -
ls -ltr myinnerdir in your home dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that working dir is a private matter of a process, so while you change the working dir of the interactive shell, the working dir of the background (printing) shell doesn't change.

On Linux (at least) with `bash` you can do this:

```
bash -c 'while sleep 3; do readlink -e /proc/$PPID/cwd; done' &
```

(`/proc/123/cwd` is a virtual symbolic link to the working dir of the process with PID 123.)

Comment: This approach works on Cygwin, but not on Linux server. `a=readlink -e /proc/$PPID/cwd;` echo $a returns null.

Comment: @syadav `a=\`readlink -e /proc/$PPID/cwd\`` (with backticks). It works on my Linux machine (kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64, Debian 8.7).